# Regular expression to collect from tweets mentions @Username but anyone retweet

Tags: python, regex

I have a lists of many tweets and I would like to extract retweets and mentions. Their schemas are: RT @Username | retweet
@Username | mention

I have collected retweets with:

```
re.findall(r'RT @\S+', text)
```

But I don't understand the formula that catches a RE, only if some characters are not present. I have tried this one for mentions but doesn't work:

```
re.findall(r'(?!RT\s)@\S+', text)
```

Why doesn't work? Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need a lookbehind regex:

```
(?<!RT\s)@\S+
```

To ignore `RT @username`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM8mH3/1)